# Can GSON handle static private nested class

Tags: android, serialization, nested, gson

I am using a design in which parent class has a `SparseArray` of `private static nested class`. Now if I try to jsonify the parent object using `GSON` library, will it be able to jsonify and de-jsonify my parent class object as nested class is not actually visible outside. code looks like this.

```
class A {
  private SparseArray<B> array = new SparseArray<B>();

  private A() {}

  private static class B {
    private B() {}
    int example;
  }
  // static public accessors to access some methods of class A, no object of A outside A
}
```

The other aspect I have is that I don't want anybody to make objects of parent class outside, so I have kept my default constructors private. I would like to know if `GSON` would perform normally or not in my code scenario.

After I convert it to `JSON` the objects inside the `SparseList` appear to be converted to null rather than jsonified objects.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide. Check the topic under Nested Classes

Comment: @Raghunandan there is no mentioning of private static nested class, they have said that static nested class works but nothing about what if they are private.

Comment: then just follow the offcicial docs.

Comment: @Raghunandan by follow the doc you mean I should make my class public??, as they haven't mentioned anything about private inner class how can I follow docs about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by using this test class, works out that `GSON` works seamlessly with every visibility modifier whether is it public or private either for class, method, instance variables or constructors. The error I was getting was due to the use of `SparseArray` and if it is replaced with `HashMap` as below it works like butter.

```
package in.mubble.mubbletest;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class GSONTest {

  private HashMap<Integer, B> myMap;
  private String extra;

  private GSONTest() {
    Log.e("GSONTest", "default constructor GSONTEST was called");
  }

  public GSONTest(String extra) {
    myMap      = new HashMap<Integer, B>(); 
    this.extra = extra;
    myMap.put(1, new B(7));
    Log.e("GSONTest", "parameter constructor GSONTEST was called");
  }

  private static class B {
    int child;
    private B() {
      Log.e("B", "default constructor B was called");
    }

    private B(int child) {
      Log.e("B", "parameter constructor B was called");
      this.child = child;  
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    return this.myMap.size() + ": " + this.extra + ", " + this.myMap.get(1).child;
  }

}
```

with test code

```
GSONTest test = new GSONTest("hahaha");
Gson gson     = new Gson();    
String json   = gson.toJson(test);
Log.e("json", json);
GSONTest result = gson.fromJson(json, GSONTest.class);
Log.e("result", result.toString());
```

this code when run generates this output on logcat

```
parameter constructor B was called
parameter constructor GSONTEST was called
{"extra":"hahaha","myMap":{"1":{"child":7}}}
default constructor GSONTEST was called
default constructor B was called
1: hahaha, 7
```